# Кодировка xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить в xmlhttprequest кодировку UTF-8 для отправки запроса кирилицей?  В логах сервера такие кракозяблы: 
"name":"?????????»?°??"

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/registration",false);
        xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

убедитесь, что :

1) ваши файлы и скрипты созданы в UTF-8,

2) ваш сервер отдает эти файлы в UTF-8

3) вы просматриваете логи веб-сервера в терминале, который поддерживает UTF-8

4) на вашем сервере установлена поддержка UTF-8

можете скачать логи веб-сервера, открыть их в текстовом редакторе и посмотреть в какой кодировке он их распознал. Если все читаемо и  редактор показывает кодировку UTF-8, значит у вас проблема с терминалом.

современные браузеры по умолчанию работают в UTF-8, поэтому, сначала проверьте это, а если у вас какой-то специфический случай, когда вы отправляете запросы со страницы в кодировке cp1251, вам, наверное нужно воспользоваться ответом @Alex Krass

вот тут https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html, например, говорится, что по умолчанию tomcat сохраняет логи в системной кодировке. там приведена инструкция по переключению логирования на log4j c utf8

Comment: Проверил в дебагере сервера (он в UTF-8) кракозябры.

Comment: что значит "проверил в дебагере сервера"? возьмите лог файлы и посмотрите как они открываются текстовым редактором

Comment: Все проделал, как вы  сказали, не нашел только логи сервера (Tomcat) использую....Пока ничего не помогло

Comment: проверьте по совету Алекса, может быть вы действительно отправляете в кодировке 1251 все. В браузере можете посмотреть в консоли разработчика, заголовки запроса.

Comment: А как можно посмотреть заголовки отправляемые из клиента (в консоли браузера можно)?

Comment: Response: Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1022
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 30 Jul 2016 18:12:18 GMT   Request: Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:310
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/static/pages/registration.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36

Comment: скорее всего что-то не то или на сервере или в способе, которым вы логи смотрите.  обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Через функцию setRequestHeader послать нужный заголовок HTTP

```
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
   client.open("POST", "/registration",false);
   client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
   client.send(formData);
```

Comment: Поменял, теперь контроллер Java на сервере не видит запрашиваемый обьект.