# Кодировка в IDEA + Eclipse

Tags: кодировка, intellij-idea, jsp, servlet

Подскажите пожалуйста. не знаю что делать. Использую IDEA. Есть проект Java EE. Крутится на Tomcat. Проблема в том что русские символы не воспринимаются вообще - вместо них знаки вопроса. Так же такая проблема есть с приходящими запросами от клиента с сайта - при отправке с клиента `ajax` способом данных, в которых есть русские символы то все эти русские символы в сервлете становятся знаками вопроса (Про эту проблему я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554514/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%BD%D0%B0-serlvet-%D1%83-java)).

Но так же эта проблема коснулась простого вывода русских симвлов в консоль. Всё что мне советовали, находил на форумах пробовал - не помогает. Выставлял и `chcp` на `866`, прописывал в мета теги на страницах, изменял кодировку самой IDEA и самого проекта и самих файлов в настройках IDEA - стоит UTF-8 везде. Уже не знаю что делать. Даже если вывести русскую строку в `jsp` файле всё равно будут знаки вопроса.

**UPD#1** - В Eclipse тоже самое. Создал проект, файл - русские символы в виде знаков вопроса.

**Пример:**

***JSP:***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="Character" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Servlet:***

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/Character")
public class Character extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        System.out.println(request.getAttribute("text"));
        System.out.println("росто текст.");

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String isbn = "978-3-16-148410-0";
        String[] isbnParts = isbn.split("-");

        String html = "<Doctype html> <html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /></head><body>";

        html = html + "префикс EAN.UCC: " + isbnParts[0] + "\n";
        html = html + "номер регистрационной группы: " + isbnParts[1] + "\n";
        html = html + "номер регистранта: " + isbnParts[2] + "\n";
        html = html + "номер издания: " + isbnParts[3] + "\n";
        html = html + "контрольная цифра: " + isbnParts[4] + "\n";

        html = html + "</body></html>";

        System.out.println(html);

        out.println(html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

кодировка IDE здесь возможно не при чем.
https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

я где-то тут же недавно на тот же вопрос отвечал уже.

вот тут отвечал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550265/208216

возможно, проблемы со шрифтами, возможно с сервером. в любом случае, надеюсь если ОП разберется, расскажет в чем проблема была.

У Idea был баг, когда она ломала кодировку файлов, но он пофикшен с полгода назад.

Comment: а может всё дело в винде? У меня стоит Windows 10 Английская. Поставил на работе IDEA, перенес проект - тут русская винда, тоже 10 и всё нормально отображается. Это мистика.

Comment: может шрифт без поддержки русского алфавита на одной из систем?  т.е. кодировки правильные везде, но отображается просто неправильно

Comment: ну там где англ версия винды русский отображается нормально. и писать нормально можно. Всё возможно. Спасибо.